# VSTS Extract zip fails with 'EPERM: operation not permitted, stat 'D:\MyFilePathHere'

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I frequently but not consistently run into `EPERM: operation not permitted, stat 'D:\MyFilePathHere` when using the 'Extract Files' Task with the Clean Destination Folder before extracting option in my Release Definition. It happen on multiple machines but has resolved itself with redeploys. Suggestions for preventing this in the future?

Edit: I have the local agents configured to run as a Network Service and I have given Network Service full control of the folder which Extract Files is working in. I have the release definition running on two different machines. The release will succeed on one and fail on the other.

`Found: 1 files to extract:
 C:\agent\_work\r2\a\App-CI\App\App.zip
 Cleaning destination folder before extraction: D:\FilePathHere
 Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, stat 'D:\FilePathHere'
 ##[error]EPERM: operation not permitted, stat 'D:\FilePathHere
 ##[section]Finishing: Install New UI Files`

Comment: Do you use private build agents? Could you share your build definition and detailed build log?

Comment: My initial finding about a folder being read only causing this were wrong. I am using a hosted build agent.

Comment: Do you use local agent or hosted agent? After solving your issue with your initial finding, does it occur again?

Comment: Hosted agent for build, local agent for on premise release. Yes it occurred again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out this is a open issue on GitHub: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/5472

It seems to be a conflict between the agent and anti-virus/security software. The way around is to use the Delete File/Folder task right before the Extract Tasks without the Clean Target Folder option.

Comment: There seems to be some hope on the horizon: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-task-lib/pull/518